# youtube sdk give services version update required error on samsung galaxy young

Tags: android, youtube

I have made an application that use youtube sdk to run youtube video inside my application it is run in almost devices but when I try it on samsung galaxy young I got this error

services version update required

so can any one help regarding this ?

Comment: its not error you must update what ever it is stating that is service version

Comment: it needs minimum version of service or youtube application that is 4.x version of you tube application it must be lower than of that

Comment: did you mean google play service ??